# Firebase orderBy query returning null

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am querying FB with in my following function:

```
  getLimit: function(artistId, limit) {
    console.log(FBURL + 
                        'songs?orderBy=\"artist_timestamp\"&startAt=\"' + 
                        artistId + 
                        '_\"&endAt=\"' + 
                        artistId +
                        '_9999\"&limitToLast=' + 
                        limit + 
                        '');

     ref= new Firebase(FBURL + 
                        'songs?orderBy=\"artist_timestamp\"&startAt=\"' + 
                        artistId + 
                        '_\"&endAt=\"' + 
                        artistId +
                        '_9999\"&limitToLast=' + 
                        limit + 
                        '');

     console.log(ref);

      ref.on('value', (snapshot) => {
        console.log("hello");
        var val = snapshot.val();
        console.log(val);
     });
     results = $firebaseArray(ref);
        results.$loaded().then(function() {
    console.log("loaded record:", results.$id);

   // To iterate the key/value pairs of the object, use angular.forEach()
   angular.forEach(results, function(value, key) {
      console.log(key, value);
   });
 });
   return results;
  }
```

When I see what URL i am calling with the first `console.log` I try to reproduce the `null` results in terminal by copy and pasting verbatim the parameter to `new Firebase()` into a curl request as follows:

```
curl "the-exact-url-except-add-dot-json"
```

this is the basic format of what I pass to `new Firebase()`:

```
https://my-proj.firebaseio.com/songs?orderBy="artist_timestamp"&startAt="foo_"&endAt="foo_9999"&limitToLast=7
```

so when I curl

```
curl 'https://my-proj.firebaseio.com/songs.json?orderBy="artist_timestamp"&startAt="foo_"&endAt="foo_9999"&limitToLast=7'
```

it works but when I take a snapshot of the former URL i get `null` in the `on('value')` callback

and I get the results I expect which is an object of `song` keys and objects.

However when I get both the snapshot of the `ref` as well as after converting to `firebaseArray` and calling the callback `$loaded` I get `null` in both cases. I am not sure what is happening that is making the results appear in terminal but not in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot pass a URL with query parameters into the Firebase constructor. Instead you add them by calling the corresponding methods on the location reference. E.g.

```
ref = new Firebase(FBURL + 'songs');
var query = ref.orderByChild("artist_timestamp")
               .startAt(artistId)
               .endAt(artistId+'_9999')
               .limitToLast(limit);
```

I also **highly** recommend that you migrate over to the "new" Firebase SDK, which is documented here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start. Using a more recent SDK (the one you're using is at least a year old) will ensure you find more helpful documentation and there is a bigger pool of developers that can help.